# Private API also should be REST API?

Tags: api, rest

I'm building this website which internally calls some APIs to interact with data in a server,
but not planning to make those APIs officially public.

Even in this case, should I make those RESTful?

Comment: What other options are you considering? What are you trying to optimize for?

Comment: I was considering "do not care about REST constraints". My current major focus is rapid prototyping but may need to implement APIs seriously...

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of trade-offs. You say you're prototyping, but may need to implement "seriously".

Firstly, even for prototyping, you get a lot of benefit from sticking with a consistent API approach, ideally based on client and server libraries in your framework of choice. Common choices are "synchronous/asynchronous", "function-based/resource-based", "JSON/XML" etc. Mixing and matching those choices just makes everything much harder.

Some business domains are great for resource-based API structures. Order management systems, social networks, question-and-answer web sites all work well. Some are not so easy to represent as resources - real-time/IoT applications, chat/messaging systems, etc.

If you decide that "synchronous" and "resource based" are a good fit for your business domain, you may as well take advantage of the libraries that exist to build and consume RESTful APIs. You can decide for yourself how "pure" and "future-proof" you want to make those APIs. You may not care about versioning, for instance.

If "synchronous" and "resource-based" are not a good fit, I'd not try to shoe horn them into a RESTful API design.

Comment: The conditions you suggested, "synchronous/asynchronous", "function-based/resource-based", "JSON/XML" are great angle I have to care about. Thank you Neville it was so insightful.

Answer (score -1):

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction. -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)

> REST is software design on the scale of decades: every detail is intended to promote software longevity and independent evolution. Many of the constraints are directly opposed to short-term efficiency. -- [Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-724)

> That doesn’t mean that I think everyone should design their own systems according to the REST architectural style. REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations. If you don’t see a need for the constraints, then don’t use them. -- [Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742)

For a private API, you probably control both the clients and the server, and its unlikely that you are going to be facing Web Scale[tm] traffic levels where you will need to offload work to caches.

Which means that you aren't likely to get full return on your investment.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, that's so helpful!